# React Native 0.70.15 - Error installing hermes-engine (curl 404)

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

Just released 2 days ago.. Seeing this error for `pod install`:

```
Installing hermes-engine (0.70.15)

[!] Error installing hermes-engine
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /temppath/file.tgz https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/download/v0.70.15/hermes-runtime-darwin-v0.70.15.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.14.3 cocoapods-downloader/2.1'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     9    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

Is there any workaround? `hermes-runtime-darwin-v0.70.15.tar.gz` doesn't appear to be available (yet).

Comment: File an issue if there's no one already. _Edit:_ https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42356

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I did a quick search but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, as of right now (Fri Jan 19 01:07:50 UTC 2024), a dirty hack to allow local development to resume (when a downgrade is not possible):

1. Download the previous version from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/download/v0.70.14/hermes-runtime-darwin-v0.70.14.tar.gz
2. Use env variable `HERMES_ENGINE_TARBALL_PATH` during Pod installation

```
HERMES_ENGINE_TARBALL_PATH=/tmp/hermes-runtime-darwin-v0.70.14.tar.gz pod install
```

Comment: This workaround is no longer necessary, as the missing file has been uploaded by Meta/Facebook. No code changes are needed (just a rebuild).